# SSMS is OK but Local IIS Cannot Connect to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I'm getting the dreaded *"A network-related or instance-specific error"* error but only when attempting to connect from my local IIS server. IIS and SQL are both installed on the same machine.

SQL Server (EXPRESS) is running and the SQL Server Browser is also running. Client Protocols (Shared Memory, TCP/IP, and Named Pipes) are all enabled. I can connect and run queries via SSMS both locally and remotely using both Named Pipes and TCP using either Windows Authentication (My Account) or a SQL Server login.

Here is the connection string I am using in my web.config

```
Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDbName;User ID=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword"
Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDbName;Integrated Security=True;
```

Any recommendations are appreciated:

- **Win Server:** 2016
- **IIS:** 10.0.14393
- **SQL Server Express:** 14.0.1

Comment: Have you tried using a period instead of "(local)"?  Are you sure the instance name is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: This was due to an additional connection string only used for Code Migration updates.